# Is it possible to duplicate payment method - WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway

Is it possible to duplicate payment method field from WooCommerce checkout page. I use following plugin: **WooCommerce ePay.bg Gateway.**
I want  ePay.bg and  ePay.bg - EasyPay  to do the same thing.

[image]

Comment: I'm curious as to why you'd want to do this? What's the benefit to the customer?

Comment: Hi, my assignor want this....ePay.bg - EasyPay redirect users to page with instructions... My assignor wants both options - ePay.bg and ePay.bg - EasyPay to redirect to page with online banking details...Thanks :)

Comment: If I had to guess, I think you will need to write your own plugin that very closely mimics ePay plugin, but changes the things you want to change. You'll almost definitely  need to read the [Payment Gateway API](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/payment-gateway-api/)